# fill table cell using array forlooped

Tags: javascript, html

I dont know how to explain my situation but instead I will just demonstrate the current output and expected output. So here is my current output

Current Output
[image]

Expected Output
[image]

This is my current code

```
$(function(){

      var a = '<?php echo $supp_dtl_1; ?>';
      a = JSON.parse(a);

      for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < a[i].unit_price.length; j++) {  

            $('#supplier-table > tbody > ').not('#tr-td-1, #tr-td-2').append(
            '<td style="width: 60px;" class="ignore"><input style="width: 160px;" type="text" class="price number supp_num-" id="price-" value="'+a[i].unit_price[j]+'" ></td>'+
            '<td style="width: 60px;"><input style="width: 160px;" value="'+a[i].total_amount[j]+'" type="text" class="total" id="total-" readonly></td>'
            );
        }
      } 


  });
```

This is the result in my variable a

[image]

My array data

```
[
 {"supplier_name":"James","unit_price":["5","100"],"total_amount":["2500","500"]},
 {"supplier_name":"Jan","unit_price":["4","400"],"total_amount":["2000","2000"]},
 {"supplier_name":"Nico","unit_price":["3","300"],"total_amount":["1500","1500"]}
]
```

If i missed some of the details just comment and I will provide. And I hope you guys can help me with this. Need your help so badly.

[**Actual Demonstration**](https://jsfiddle.net/solomon099/yzkhrn1t/4/)

Comment: Please provide Html code.

Comment: Show us your `a` Array. We have no idea what that looks like.

Comment: Please see my update post

Comment: Please see the actual demonstration above